# Is there a way to list the local dns cache?

Tags: shell, cache, dns

I would like to get a list of my current cache on my phone, what is the command to issue in order to retrieve that list ?

I would like to get a command and not an app that does that, since i want to incorporate that command into a script that i am write.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

In Android, the DNS Cache is not on the OS level (Linux), but on the Java level (managed by [java.net.InetAddress](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html)). Therefore, it is not possible to list the cache contents from the shell, however you can access it from the Java code.

Please see [Java DNS cache viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835421/java-dns-cache-viewer) question on StackOverflow, one of the answers has a sample Java code that prints the positive and negative DNS cache. You can incorporate that code into whatever solution you're building.