# Android get dns history

Tags: dns, history

Can I get the dns history on android like on windows?

Like this: `ipconfig /displaydns`

Comment: You can use [os monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor) , it gives fair details on *Connection* tab

Comment: not working, not gives the dns history

Comment: I believe your answer is a duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18002/is-there-a-way-to-list-the-local-dns-cache